# Does MATLAB offer a more elegant way to iterate through 3D array to get 3rd dimension vectors?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, multidimensional-array, iteration

I'm trying to iterate trough a fixed size 3d array in order to plot the 3rd vector dimension like this:

```
%respo is a 3D array of fixed size defined above
for ii = 1:size(respo,1)
    for jj = 1:size(respo,2)
        plot(squeeze(respo(ii,jj,1:8)))
    end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this than by 2 level for loop with pointing exactly to the vector plotted at each iteration?

I get there is a linear indexing for each array in MATLAB, but I struggle to come up with a way that saves from the double-looping.

Comment: Nowadays it's no longer important to avoid loops at all costs. Especially if the code is clearly readable as it is here I would keep them.

Comment: I have to say I found both answers and all comments useful, so thank you guys! However, yhe one-liner by @luis-mendo is the one I used, however, since it facilitates those MATLAB functions to the extent they are designed the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot` applied to a matrix plots the columns of that matrix. So: rearrange dimensions such that the third becomes the new first and the others get combined into the new second, and then just call `plot`

```
plot(reshape(permute(respo, [3 1 2]), size(respo,3), []))
```

Comment: This seems to be the way to go, note that if the original code would use `hold on` rather than `hold all` one could mimic this by adding `,'b'` as additional input to the plot command.

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess you could reshape it to only need one loop:

```
respo_2D = reshape(respo, [], size(respo,3))
```

So now

```
for ii = 1:size(respo_2D, 1)
    plot(respo(ii,1:8));
end
```

(or potentially even `plot(respo_2D(:,1:8)')` depending on what you're trying to do)